# How to create horizontal planes that follow exponential growth function in scheme programming?

Tags: function, scheme, exponent, do-loops

I want to create horizontal surfaces along the y-direction that follow the exponential growth function: *y = 3.1268*e^(0.7234*x)*
The program that I use implements scheme language, which I am not much familiar with. 
The x values change from 1 to 10, so I want to create 10 planes. I have earlier created something similar, but the planes are at an equal distance from each other:

```
    (Do ((i 20 (+ i 20))) ((> i 500))
)
```

Command in the program I use that which creates the surfaces, with *i* passed to it as the y dimension

I think the procedure will, maybe, look something like:

```
    (let ((y 0))
     (Do ((i 1 (+ i 10))) ((> i 100))
      y = 3.1268*e^(0.7234*x)
   Command to create the planes...with y passed to it...
)
```

How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell us which program you're actually using. Scheme implementation might be pretty different from each others. The `Do` construct looks like a macro of some kind.